# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (right port)

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

I would like to print the measured data of my weatherstation on a website. Therefore I would like to connect my MariaDB-database. Here ist my code.

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "M1lVhPuio";
$database = "weatherbot";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=raspberrypi;port=3306;database=$database", $username, $password);
    //Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. ". $e->getMessage());
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Wetterstation </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Meine Wetterdaten </h1>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the website, I see this: "ERROR: Could not connect. SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

There's already an entry in this forum about this case, but adding the port didn't work for me. (3306 is the right port.)

Comment: The host "raspberrypi" is your local computer? if not you should check if your mysql server "bind-address" configuration ( /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf ), default address should be '127.0.0.1' ( access only from local ). 

Before make any changes to your configuration just try to connect using your  credentials from a local terminal and see if you can access.

Comment: From the terminal it's possible to access with the user and password I typed in. I can't find the file you mentioned. I only have /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf and /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf Both don't contain any bind-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Sergio Rinaudo said, I had to use the default address instead of "raspberrypi":

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=3306;database=database", root, M1lVhPuio);
```

Thank you for your help!